# mail() is Incorrectly Sending Emails to cPanel Default Account

Tags: php, email, mx-record

I purchased a domain from GoDaddy and linked it to Office 365 (via MX records). This means I have several email accounts in Outlook that are @mydomain.com.

Example Outlook accounts:

- sales@mydomain.com
- contact@mydomain.com
- matt@mydomain.com

I can send/receive emails through those accounts.

---

My website is hosted on basic web hosting with a cPanel installation, which means I was given a "default" email account. For example: `default@mydomain.com`. I wrote a PHP script on my website (contact form) that sends emails via `mail()` to `contact@mydomain.com`.

However all the emails are sent to the default cPanel account `default@mydomain.com` instead of the Outlook account `contact@mydomain.com`.

To test, I tried sending the emails to my personal account that is not hosted on mydomain and it works as expected. Emails are sent instantly.

How come my website incorrectly send emails to the Outlook accounts? Thanks for your time.

---

EDIT:

The script was requested:

```
<?php

    $uploadedFile = $statusMsg = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($message))
        {
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $uploadStatus = 1;

                if(!empty($_FILES["attach"]["name"]))
                {
                    $targetDir = "uploads/";
                    $fileName = basename($_FILES["attach"]["name"]);
                    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
                    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attach"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath))
                    {
                        $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $uploadStatus = 0;
                        $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
                }

                if($uploadStatus == 1)
                {
                    $name = $first_name.' '.$last_name;

                    $mailTo = "contact@mydomain.com";//changed to my real outlook account

                    $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                    <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                    <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                    <p><b>Phone:</b> '.$phone.'</p>
                    <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';

                    // Header for sender info
                    $headers = "From: $name"." <".$email.">";


                    if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile))
                    {
                        // Boundary 
                        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

                        // Headers for attachment 
                        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

                        // Multipart boundary 
                        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 

                        // Preparing attachment
                        if(is_file($uploadedFile)){
                            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                            $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                            $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                            @fclose($fp);
                            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                            $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                            "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                        }

                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                        $returnpath = "-f" . $email;

                        // Send email
                        $mail = mail($mailTo, "Contact Form Submission from ".$name, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

                        // Delete attachment file from the server
                        @unlink($uploadedFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                        $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                        $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";

                        // Send email
                        $mail = mail($mailTo, 'Contact Form Submission from '.$name, $htmlContent, $headers); 
                    }

                    // If mail sent
                    if($mail)
                    {
                        $statusMsg = "Your message has been sent. Thanks!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $statusMsg = 'Your contact request submission failed, please try again.';
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $statusMsg = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $statusMsg = "Please fill out the required information.";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: We need more details, starting from code with mail sending.

Comment: It's a big script with support for email attachments and it works with any "to" address I give it. but sure, I'll edit.

Comment: Talk to your host. Chances are that they configured your domain for mail on that same server. Most MTAs will never even look at DNS if the domain exists locally.

Comment: It's just to make sure that the script is correct to exclude possible cause of the problem.

Comment: PHP won't change the destination by itself, it must be happening somewhere in the mail software.

Comment: @Sammitch Ah I didn't know that! So it's recognizing that it's trying to send to the same domain and it just skips right to cPanel? Interesting.

Comment: Avoid using `mail()` in PHP anyway for many reasons. Ideally you should use a commercial-grade email gateway such as (and this is not an endorsment) SendGrid, which have a Web-service for sending email which is more reliable than PHP's `mail()` or attempting to use SMTP directly from PHP. For example: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-php-code-example/

Comment: @Dai I plan to, however I wanted to first get the basics working ya know? And my web host blocks port 25 so my options there are limited.

Comment: @mrg95 If your host blocks port 25 then you can't use `mail()` anyway, unless it's using something like a pickup directory.

Comment: Your webhost probably blocks inbound port 25. That shouldn't stop you connecting to a remote host on 25 (or even better, a secure mail transport port)

Comment: @Dai The `mail()` call works when emails are sent to a different address. But they don't allow sending mail from their web hosting package as if it was a mail server. For that I would need to get their VPS package. That's what they told me at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change my cPanel "Email Routing" option to "Remote" in order for all local emails to first check with the MX records.

[image]